Throwing away a single register
I asked a question a couple of months ago about getting rid of a single not entangled register (link to the question).
Now I have a related question. Consider a state $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle$.
We can get rid of the first register by applying partial trace by the first subspace: $\rho_2 = \mathrm{Tr}_1 \rho_{12}$.
How can I formulate this formally as a lemma/statement? What mathematically correct formulation could this fact have?
I’ve tried something like: “Consider the state $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle$, where $\psi_1 \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $\psi_2 \in \mathcal{H}_2$. The state $|\psi_2\rangle$ could be treated independently from the state $|\psi_2\rangle$.”
However, the last sentence sounds not quite mathematically correct. How can I say, that the first register may be safely thrown away?

Is the formal statement you're interested in something like "If $|\psi\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle|\psi_2\rangle$, then ${\rm tr}_1(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|$"? Or if not, what is the statement you're interested in (your question is not too clear to me)?

@FrederikvomEnde not quite. I’m interested in the something like “If we have two not entangled registers, then we could get rid of one of them and work with another one safely (like the first one does not exist)”. But I need this statement to sound more formally.

You're probably looking for something like the no-communication theorem.
The "this state can be treated independently of this other state" part simply means that you want them to be separable. If the initial state is separable, which is the case you mention in your question, then the density matrix is also a tensor product of the partial traces:
$$\begin{align*}
\rho_{12}&=\left|\psi_1,\psi_2\middle\rangle\!\middle\langle\psi_1,\psi_2\right|\\
&=\left|\psi_1\middle\rangle\!\middle\langle\psi_1\right|\otimes\left|\psi_2\middle\rangle\!\middle\langle\psi_2\right|\\
&= \rho_1\otimes\rho_2\,.
\end{align*}$$
As long as you apply operations on the first register only, the second register is going to stay in the same state, and reciprocally. This is why you can "treat them independently of the other".
The proof is just a single line: if you apply a quantum operation $\Phi$ that acts only on the first register, it means that it can be written as $\Phi_1\otimes\mathrm{id}$, with $\mathrm{id}$ being the identity function on the second register, and thus $\Phi\left(\rho_{12}\right)=\Phi_1\left(\rho_1\right)\otimes\rho_2$.

As a side note, you even have a more powerful result: even if both registers are entangled, which then means that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not pure anymore, this property remains true: no matter what operation you apply on the first register, as long as you don't touch the other one ("touch" can be large here, one way to think about it is: no operation acting on both registers nor classical communication between the two parties holding the registers), its state won't change.
For instance, suppose the initial state is $\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, and suppose the first qubit is given to Alice, and the second is given to Bob. As long as Alice and Bob don't communicate, every operation Bob does on his state doesn't change Alice's. However, if Bob were to, for instance, measure his state in the computational basis and tell the result to Alice, this would change her view about the state she holds.
